# How to turn on pose mode with scripting?

Tags: scripting, pose-mode

I don't know how to activate the pose mode in blender 2.8 with python. If anyone knows how to please consider informing.

Answer (score 2):

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle()
```

but it will only work with an armature object selected

Comment: You can override with 
`bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle({"active_object": bpy.data.objects["Armature"]})`